# UISearchController in non-UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisearchcontroller

I have a situation where I'd like to use a UISearchController to allow searching/filtering the contents of a UITableView. The behavior I want is IDENTICAL to what Apple does in the Contacts app where the search bar stays pinned to the top of the table view, content scrolling underneath. When the search bar is tapped, I want the default behavior of the bar animating to cover the navigation bar with results below, again just like Apple contacts.

I've made a sample app to isolate things and have paired it down to the following search controller init code. This VC is the root view controller of a UINavigationController with a translucent nav bar.

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f);
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

This results in two issues: 1) The search bar does not expand height to 64px so you still see what's behind the status bar and 2) whenever you push an item onto the navigation stack and then go back, the content in the parent view (table view) jumps.

I've seen a ton of confusion around UISearchcontroller, so I'm not terribly optimistic that someone has a good solution, but trying anyway.